# dongle check happen before a debugger start debugging

Tags: windows, anti-debugging, x64dbg, dongle

i'm trying to fake the test ( dongle exist )
but one problem that i encounter is that the application detect it before i start debugging it .

> this is what happen with more details  : open( not attaching) the
>   target programme in x64dbg before anything ( what i mean is that the
>   debugger still  loading moduals and ...) a pop-up show up with an
>   message "you need the dongle usb key " aftre that message the debugger
>   disassembly panel show up with eip at the kernel address of nt dll

**my questions:**

1. is this is a type of anti-Reverse Engineering?
2. how i bypass this type of protection ( if it is a protection ) ?

**my working env:**

1. x64dbg
2. win 7 64bit

Comment: did u try : hiding debugger

Comment: yes but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

It could be a TLS callback. Some debuggers have an option to break earlier.
I suggest you use [procmon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see who and when an handle is opened for your USB dongle.